# MYSQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'usernamei'@'hostname' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

HI guys I got this Error and after Looking Around, the suggestion is that the password is wrong but I do not Understand how the Password Can be wrong because I can connect using the same details using phpMyadmin. Why should the Commandline give me this error?

I have been connecting using the command:

```
mysql -h db.gatungo.gskool.com -u mungai -p
 Enter password: **********
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'mungai'@'212.22.177.50' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: What you have tried ? Please provide your code here .

Comment: Error 1045 is explained here: http://www.webyog.com/faq/content/23/18/en/error-no-1045-connection-denied.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change `hostname` to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

I don't believe `hostname` is a valid host.

Note that you also have the username as `usernamei`

```
mysql -u usernamei -h localhost -p
```

Also make sure you have access from outside for that user:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO  'mungai'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY  'YOUR_PASSWORD';
```

Comment: I think that was just an example, I have pasted the Actual Process.

Comment: I tried this way i got this message `#1045 - Access denied for user 'mungai'@'64.90.32.0/255.255.224.0' (using password: YES)`

Comment: Try you add based on IP ? First try to add all of them `%` to see if it works